# Flutter File_picker MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to install file picker except that when my button is clicked or the file picker function is assigned, I have this error that appears: "MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method any on channel miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker))"

I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Did you rebuild your app? Might be necessary when installing plugin using native functionnality.

Comment: can you include your test device and don't forget to follow installation process.

Comment: I've delete all my project. 
Then i reinstall fill_picker packets, and now, when i'm trying to run my app, I have 
    2022-10-26 22:03:49.020 xcodebuild[4259:33198] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-10-26 22:03:49.020 xcodebuild[4259:33198] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExte ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image_picker and file_picker don't work well with the ios simulator. You have to use a real device instead.

Comment: Ok thx I will try with my real device

Comment: Just adding the file picker dependencies makes me unable to build my application

Comment: make sure you added all the permission needed for ios then, run `flutter pub get` , `flutter clean` then `flutter run`..don't forget to always run flutter pub get before clean.

Comment: Have u any about iOS permissions ?

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup#ios)

Comment: I only just stopped and rebuilt the app on my android device and it ran well.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your application. When ever a new plugin is installed it is better to restart the application.
I also faced this problem with file picker, restarting the application worked for me.

Comment: I prefer to stop running first, then start again, instead of restarting the application.

Answer (score 0):

in your project path use this command

> `flutter clean`

Comment: Already done but nothing changes

Comment: do you test on real device or ios simulator ?

Comment: iOS simulator .

Comment: Try real device as it dont work on somilator
And be sure that you used the permisions on info plist